# A transfer error has occurred using webusb in chrome for pl2303 based device

Tags: javascript, websub

I have a device pl2303 device ,that I am trying to connect with web usb .I am able to get data in mac chrome in linux ,but the process is failing with windows.
Earlier I was getting `Access Denied` Error on windows
I solved it by replacing the native windows driver with winusb driver using zadig

See screenshot
[image]

Now I am getting the `pl2303.js:111 DOMException: A transfer error has occurred`
How to resolve this ? .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had enabled the flag in Enable new USB backend in chrome://flags/#new-usb-backend

I changed it to default and it worked